# How do I control the default gateway for my internet connection?

Tags: networking, routing, networkmanager

I've got two ways to connect to the internet. ( via wireless eduroam)

```
(1) My laptop's wireless card
(2) My phone, propped in the window, bluetooth tethered to my laptop
```

Connection (1) is fast, low ping, not much packet drop, but curiously intermittent.
Connection (2) has a much higher ping, lots of packet drops, but is always up.

`ip route` gives:

```
default via 192.168.44.1 dev bnep0 src 192.168.44.72 metric 377
default via 10.248.31.254 dev wlp2s0 src 10.248.15.216 metric 476
```

This is the wrong way round! It always uses the bad connection, even when both are available.

How do I say 'use wlp2s0 (connection 1) if available, only if that's down use bnep0 (connection 2)?

My laptop's running debian

```
cat /etc/debian_version 
9.12
```

And the connections are being handled by Network-Manager, if that's relevant.

Comment: Can you control the metric? The lower valued one will always win.

Answer (score 1):

during the routing process the most specific route is taken. If two routes have the same level, other criteria are used to decide (i.e. the metric).

Since you only have default routes, they share the same level of specification. The easiest way to control which connection is preferred is to change the metric.
Unfortunatly it is not possible to change the metric directly, so you have to remove and add the gateway with the updated metric:

```
sudo route del ...
sudo route add ... metric 100
```